When making a simple calculator program in Python, every operation returns the last number typed in
Made this calculator program, but whenever it tries to calculate using the operation I select, no matter which one, it returns the last number. What is wrong with my code?
from time import sleep

# Find function wanted by user
while True:
    operation = input("Would you like to Add, Subtract, Multiply, or Divide(A, S, M, D)? ")
    if operation.upper() in ["A", "S", "M", "D"]:
        break
    else: 
        print("Please only enter A, S, M, or D.")
        sleep(1)

# Find amount of numbers user wants to use
while True:
    amount_of_numbers = (input("How many numbers would you like to use(2-5)? "))
    if amount_of_numbers.isdigit():
        amount_of_numbers = int(amount_of_numbers)
        if 2 <= amount_of_numbers <= 5:
            break
        else:
            print("The amount of numbers must be between 2 and 5.")
            sleep(1)
    else:
        print("Please enter a whole number without anything else added.")
        sleep(1)


# Get the numbers
while amount_of_numbers > 0:
    total = [0]
    chosen_number = input("Type a number. ")
    def isnumber(chosen_number):
        
        try:
            float(chosen_number)
            return True
        except ValueError:
            return False
    
    if isnumber(chosen_number):
        total.append(float(chosen_number))
        amount_of_numbers -= 1
    else:
        print ("Please enter a number.")
        sleep(1)
# Remove placeholder from list
total.remove(0)

#? This part is failing, maybe has to do with very top?
from math import prod 
if operation.upper() == "A":
    result = sum(total)
    print(f"The sum is {result:.2f}.")
elif operation.upper() == "S":
    result = total[0] - sum(total[1:])
    print(f"The difference is {result:.2f}.")
elif operation.upper() == "M":
    result = prod(total)
    print(f"The product is {result:.2f}.")
elif operation.upper() == "D":
    divider = prod(total[1:])
    result = total[0] / divider
    print(f"The quotient is {result:.2f}.")

When typing any operation, no matter the numbers typed in, it returns the last number typed in.

You are initializing total inside the while amount_of_numbers > 0: loop - so it never contains more than a single number.  Move the initialization above the loop.  And there's no point in initializing to [0] and then deleting that zero, just start with an empty list.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

As jasonharper commented, initialize the list total before the while-loop, not inside. And get rid of the unnecessary 0, that you use as a placeholder.
from time import sleep

# Find function wanted by user
while True:
    operation = input("Would you like to Add, Subtract, Multiply, or Divide(A, S, M, D)? ")
    if operation.upper() in ["A", "S", "M", "D"]:
        break
    else: 
        print("Please only enter A, S, M, or D.")
        sleep(1)

# Find amount of numbers user wants to use
while True:
    amount_of_numbers = (input("How many numbers would you like to use(2-5)? "))
    if amount_of_numbers.isdigit():
        amount_of_numbers = int(amount_of_numbers)
        if 2 <= amount_of_numbers <= 5:
            break
        else:
            print("The amount of numbers must be between 2 and 5.")
            sleep(1)
    else:
        print("Please enter a whole number without anything else added.")
        sleep(1)

total = []
# Get the numbers
while amount_of_numbers > 0:
    chosen_number = input("Type a number. ")
    def isnumber(chosen_number):
        
        try:
            float(chosen_number)
            return True
        except ValueError:
            return False
    
    if isnumber(chosen_number):
        total.append(float(chosen_number))
        amount_of_numbers -= 1
    else:
        print ("Please enter a number.")
        sleep(1)

from math import prod
 
if operation.upper() == "A":
    result = sum(total)
    print(f"The sum is {result:.2f}.")
elif operation.upper() == "S":
    result = total[0] - sum(total[1:])
    print(f"The difference is {result:.2f}.")
elif operation.upper() == "M":
    result = prod(total)
    print(f"The product is {result:.2f}.")
elif operation.upper() == "D":
    divider = prod(total[1:])
    result = total[0] / divider
    print(f"The quotient is {result:.2f}.")

If you initialize the list total inside the same while-loop, you use, to append something to total, then it gets initialized again on every execution of the loop and therefore contains only one value after the loop has finished.

This works, but why? How does this make it work? What's the reasoning behind it?

@user25395407 I added additional information to my answer. Feel free to ask further if anything is still unclear.
